# Use pomegranate: how to generate probabilities in Hidden Markov Model

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models, unsupervised-learning, markov

For training a HMM model, I need start probabilities (pi), the  transition probabilities, and emission probabilities. Now I want to train a HMM model with 3 states (1,2,3) and 4  outputs (a,b,c, d).  The training data is:

`[[abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdbacbacd,abababcdcdcdcdababab,badcacdabacdbbacd,dacdbacdbbccaaadacdbabd,cababcacdbacacdbdacdacdbacdbab,acddbaacbdcaabdcbabd,cdbadcbacdbbdacdbcdaaabd,bcadabbacbacdbdacddb]]`

I am trying to use pomegranate to do that, but in the example all of the states have probabilities specified like this:

```
rainy = State( DiscreteDistribution({ 
    'walk': 0.1, 'shop': 0.4, 'clean': 0.5 }),
    name='Rainy' )
sunny = State( DiscreteDistribution({ 
    'walk': 0.6, 'shop': 0.3, 'clean': 0.1 }), 
    name='Sunny' )`
```

My problem is how to get the probabilities. I am trying to  use pomegranate method `model.add_transition()` , but I don't know which parameter I should give?  Is there any example that can teach me how to  get the probability in my data?

Comment: Try [**this link**](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate/issues/485) at Github

Comment: Beware pomegranate is still pretty buggy and with skimpy documentation. Brace yourself for a rough ride.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not know the parameters of the desired model i.e. you want to use model to learn those parameters, then in the unsupervised setting, you can use `fit()` function from pomegranate.
    
    `model = HiddenMarkovModel() #create reference
    model.fit(sequences, algorithm='baum-welch') # let model fit to the data
    model.bake() #finalize the model`

(Note: Make sure each of the sequence you are feeding in is a list or numpy array)

Once the model has learned the parameters, you can use below functions to extract results:

1. To get the transition probability matrix:

   `model.dense_transition_matrix()`
2. To get the emission distributions:

   `print(model)`
3. Then if you wish to use the model to generate samples:

   `model.sample(length=10)`
4. You can further improve the model by adjusting using transition and emission parameters above, as you see fit, and creating new model by:

   `custom_model = HiddenMarkovModel.from_matrix(transition_matrix, distributions, start_probs, end_probs)`

Pomegranate [docs](https://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the best source to get the details of each of these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Pomegranate is a tool that can give you the state labels (or probabilities) for the sequence that you model using HMM. Pomegranate can figure out the Start Probabilities, Transition Probabilities, and Emission Probabilities for you given that you give us initial transition probabilities, emission probabilities based on your domain knowledge of the problem. [This](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate/blob/master/docs/tutorials/B_Model_Tutorial_4_Hidden_Markov_Models.ipynb) is a good starting point for HMM using Pomegranate.

Comment: So how do I use pomegranates to help me with those odds? Any examples can give me a reference????? thx your ans